# PDO throws an uncaught exception halfway through my MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've had this issue before and can't for the life of me figure out what keeps causing it. I have a PDO statement that looks like this

```
$fields = "
    `ProgramName`  = :programName,
    `TotalUnits`   = :totalUnits,
    `UnitCost`     = :unitCost,
    `Description`  = :description,
    `CreationDate` = NOW()
";

$description = isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : null;

$insertProgram = $dbHandle -> prepare("INERT INTO `Programs` SET $fields");
$insertProgram -> bindParam(':programName', $_POST['programName'] );
$insertProgram -> bindParam(':totalUnits' , $_POST['totalUnits']  );
$insertProgram -> bindParam(':unitCost'   , $_POST['unitCost']    );
$insertProgram -> bindParam(':description', $description          );
$insertProgram -> execute();
```

The Error is the generic old "

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064...check the manual for the correct syntax to use near.
>
> `ProgramName`  = ?,
>           `TotalUnits`   = ?,
>           `Uni' at line 1

See where it cuts off "UnitCost", even thought it's a perfectly formatted string in $fields? What in the world causes this? I'm using back-ticks on all of my column names...

Comment: `INERT` probably isn't helping matters.

Comment: Agree with @JonStirling.  The code above would throw a syntax error on `INERT`, so you've clearly changed your code for the purposes of posting an minimal example here (thank you) but those simplifications may also be masking your underlying error as changing `INERT` to `INSERT` shouldn't produce the error you cite.

Comment: OK, that was definately the issue (how dumb of me). So now for the real question, WHY was the error message so damn obscure? Stopping halfway through my fields made me think I had some invisible character in the string somehow... (@eggyal, as it turns out that WAS the error. HAHAAH. But I reiterate my above question. WHY MySql, WHY?)

Comment: It's generally the beginning of those kinds of errors you want to be looking at (and the error is usually before the bit that's output). As for why, who knows. Probably simpler than getting the parser to try and work out exactly what's wrong with the query, it just knows "well, something wasn't right when we got to this point".

Comment: Fair enough I suppose, But I feel like obscure error messages are kind of a "thing" with MySQL. Really wish they would fix that... Anyway, Thanks for the extra sets of eyes everyone. Still a bit baffled by just how obscure this error truly was. Sorry to post a "Typo" question >:|

Comment: No worries. I kinda agree with you that the messages are perhaps a bit too cryptic, but if it's that or having to wait extra `x` milliseconds for a query (one of what could be _a lot_ of queries) I'll take the cryptic messages ;)

Comment: Agreed. Maybe we should vote on a "debug" mode for mysql that throws helpful error messages. Then we could just turn it off for production. VOILA! :P

Comment: I'd +1 that feature ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error.

For a query like this

```
INERT into test SET foo='11111111111111111111111111111111111', bar='2222222222222222222222222222222';
```

it is giving me the error

> the right syntax to use near 'INERT into test SET foo='11111111111111111111111111111111111', bar='222222222222' at line 1

which conforms to my experience when mysql is showing the query part that's immediately following the problem part.

And the answer to your question "Why mysql does cut the original query at all" is fairly simple: the query could be up to 2 megabytes long or even more. And you apparently don't want an *error message* of that size.

Comment: We worked out the answer in the comments above. It's definatly the "INERT" typo. I'm just wondering why it cuts off the SQL that comes directly after the error. It even did so on yours. You see how there's only like 10 '2's instead of 15 or 20? It cut off that snipped like halfway through. It just mislead me for a bit. that's all.

Comment: @NativeCoder this is standard behavior for MySQL syntax errors. Definitely not the best/most friendly for the developer, but it's the way it is

Comment: It is not mysql, but you who cut the statement, posting only irrelevant part of the error message in the question.

Comment: While I did post only the relevant part of the message my point still remains valid. The error message cuts off the sql midway through the statement. It even did so on yours. Look at it. It doesn' who the entire query, only part of it. It shows "bar='222222222222' but you set bar to '222222222222222222' <- There were way more '2s' than sql shows in the error.

Comment: @NativeCoder I updated my post with an answer to this last question of yours.